# Cordova SqlLite plugin throws os_xpc_error on iOS 9

Tags: cordova, ios9

I'm using Cordova 2.2 and [davibe's SQLite plugin](https://github.com/davibe/Phonegap-SQLitePlugin).  As of iOS 9, the application has stopped working, constantly crashing with a memory warning.

I upgraded to Cordova 5.4.0 and Cordova-ios 4.0.1 along with [brodybits' SQLite Plugin](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage): The only error I ever get is coming from iOS and it's quite vague: it's simply an `os_xpc_error`, communication interrupted.

Please see the attached image (iOS 8.4 above, iOS 9.2.1 below) [Memory Usage in iOS 8 vs iOS 9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yf3K7.png.)

How do I resolve this issue in iOS9?

Comment: You've included way too much information; we just need a simple reproduction of the issue; the versions of each plugin you're using (get it from the cordova command for that plugin or your package.json), and the error and what you expect to happen.  You could very easily wipe out 75% of this question and still have an answerable question.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker, thanks for the advice.  However, I believe some of that extraneous information may be necessary to state how we are using Cordova (which is simply a wrapper for an external code base -- namely, none of our app code actually lives within the Cordova project, but is downloaded via a URL.).  I was also trying to show that we are using app cache for the app itself and SQLite to store a 'large' amount of data.  I'm also new to posting on Stack Overflow, so I'm trying to show people I'm actually trying things, not looking for a handout :)

Comment: It's not necessary.  I use cordova for a living.  I also help maintain [ng-cordova](http://github.com/driftyco/ng-cordova).

Comment: What we do need, however, is a sample set of code that reproduces the issue you're having, and that's what is missing currently.

Comment: Unfortunately, given the complexity of our solution, (custom SPA framework, C# Message Bus, CRM back end, custom database for storing our JSON), I don't know how I'd be able to provide that without giving out the URL to our app.  I can't do this as it contains sensitive client data.  I was hoping for another direction to look -perhaps someone using the latest version of Cordova-iOS and the same SQLite plugin that has run into this error.  Or perhaps, if there's someone which has experienced a problem with garbage collection or something that's changed in terms of available app memory in iOS 9.

Comment: If you believe it's a problem with the SQL-Lite plugin, then your first step is to reproduce the issue *just with the SQL Lite plugin*. If you find that you can't reproduce it with a stock Cordova application, then the problem isn't with SQL lite, it's somewhere in your code base.  So either way, before you come to us, you have to be sure where the problem is, and that means reproducing it in a simple Cordova app with just SqlLite.

Comment: If I can sanitize the log produced by the app, might that help?

Comment: Not really; we need to be able to reproduce the issue on our own. Again, you have to make a sample basic app with just cordova and just sql lite. If you still encounter the issue, then it's not your framework; it's the plugin. If you can't reproduce the issue, then the issue isn't with the SqlLite Plugin. That's really important to discern if you want to fix the issue. There are no easy ways out.

Comment: Also looks like Cordova 6 was just released. Which supports iOS9 http://cordova.apache.org/news/2016/01/28/tools-release.html

Comment: I just that pop up in my terminal window :)  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem ended up being that one of our JSON objects was too large to process in memory.  I moved it to the app cache instead of SQLite.  It's odd that it was too large only for iOS 9.